# How to get login history of a facebook user

Tags: facebook, api

How can I get the login history of a facebook user?

I want to get a timestamp; when user successfully logged in to facebook using facebook.com. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Facebook API which can be used to retrieve that information